# How to position Dropdown List below dataTable in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a Shiny App. I am facing an issue in positioning the selectInput() below DataTable.

```
fluidRow(
    column(3,dataTableOutput("table", height = "40px")),
    column(9,uiOutput("inputGroup")),
    column(9,textOutput("text1"))
      ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           selectizeInput("proj1", NULL,
                          choices = Dummy$Project_1,
                          options = list(
                            placeholder = "Additional Projects",
                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')

                          )
           ))),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           selectizeInput("proj2", NULL,
                          choices = Dummy$Project_1,
                          options = list(
                            placeholder = "Additional Projects",
                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')

                          )
           )))
```

This is the **RCode** used.

The output of this is below:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: That is because your `uiOutput` height is far larger than that of `dataTableOutput` which is increasing the height of fluidRow. You can increase the height of the `dataTableOutput` to match it with the height of `uiOutput`.

Comment: Is there any other solution other than this?

Comment: You could have a `sidebarLayout` and put the `datatable` and `selectInput` in the `sidebarPanel`

Comment: I guess I can help, just post a sceenshot of your expected output

Comment: The two drop-down list box should be aligned with the last two rows of textBoxes.. Is it clear?  @Rahul

Comment: Yes, I got it. But from your above sample code, I am not able to re-create the similar UI. Can you please put the code for the above UI